# Weibull boot.pdf error in R : finite values needed for L-BFGS-B

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to plot Weibull pdf and cdf in R using the following code, I get a problem that I believe comes from the first block, where I define boot.pdf, I get this error :

> Error in stats::optim(x = c(0.606792325222066, 0.606792325222066,
>   0.426032294982964,  :    L-BFGS-B requires finite values of 'fn'

This error happens also when I use only 5 random numbers instead of 100.

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 5. Bootstrapping the pointwise confidence intervals
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

set.seed(123)

rw.small <- rweibull(100,shape=1.5, scale=1)

xs <- seq(0, 5, len=500)


boot.pdf <- sapply(1:1000, function(i) {
  xi <- sample(rw.small, size=length(rw.small), replace=TRUE)
  MLE.est <- suppressWarnings(fitdistr(xi, densfun="weibull", lower = 0))  
  dweibull(xs, shape=as.numeric(MLE.est[[1]][13]), scale=as.numeric(MLE.est[[1]][14]))
}
)

boot.cdf <- sapply(1:1000, function(i) {
  xi <- sample(rw.small, size=length(rw.small), replace=TRUE)
  MLE.est <- suppressWarnings(fitdistr(xi, densfun="weibull", lower = 0))  
  pweibull(xs, shape=as.numeric(MLE.est[[1]][15]), scale=as.numeric(MLE.est[[1]][16]))
}
)   

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Plot PDF
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

par(bg="white", las=1, cex=1.2)
plot(xs, boot.pdf[, 1], type="l", col=rgb(.6, .6, .6, .1), ylim=range(boot.pdf),
     xlab="x", ylab="Probability density")
for(i in 2:ncol(boot.pdf)) lines(xs, boot.pdf[, i], col=rgb(.6, .6, .6, .1))

# Add pointwise confidence bands

quants <- apply(boot.pdf, 1, quantile, c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975))
min.point <- apply(boot.pdf, 1, min, na.rm=TRUE)
max.point <- apply(boot.pdf, 1, max, na.rm=TRUE)
lines(xs, quants[1, ], col="red", lwd=1.5, lty=2)
lines(xs, quants[3, ], col="red", lwd=1.5, lty=2)
lines(xs, quants[2, ], col="darkred", lwd=2)
#lines(xs, min.point, col="purple")
#lines(xs, max.point, col="purple")
```

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to run `dweibull(xs, ...)`: the density should be evaluated at some suitable `x` values rather than at a sample of weibull random numbers.

Also it is not clear to me what you achieve to do: do you want a bootstrap estimator of the scale and shape parameters?

Comment: I did this eventually in R, I don't remember the exact necessity now , it's a last year question